# Prepare PDO sql statement with variable to call values on

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, so obviously the code I have now doesn't work

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :p');
foreach($stmt->execute(array(':p' => $_GET['p'])) as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

but, hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do. I want to return values from an sql entry that are related to id whatever. I'm not exactly sure what combination of prepare, execute, or query I need to use to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: `execute()` returns true or false, not an array. You just call `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` in a while loop, or `$stmt->fetchAll()` to get an array. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE id = :p');

$stmt->execute(array(':p' => $_GET['p']));

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

---

I highly recommend taking a look at what each of these individual methods do:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking there but there's just so much stuff and so much to take in it got intimidating. Thanks again.

Comment: foreach ( $stmt as $row) is possible too, but after the execute() call